# Creating an HTTP server in NodeMCU through an access point created by the board

Tags: http, lua, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I am coding a robot, using NodeMCU ([ESP8266](http://www.esp8266.com/)) and want it to be remote controlled. My current solution is connecting to a nearby router, to the internet and creating a TCP HTTP server. Data is streamed from the mobile device (remote) to the NodeMCU (robot) via HTTP requests. The remote is loaded onto the mobile device through a browser with HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

What I want instead is for the NodeMCU to create its own hotspot, because:

- A router is not required
- The connection is more direct

I want the same TCP HTTP solution, but I don't know how to serve a webpage through a custom hotspot.

This is my code:

```
-- Connect to router
wifi.sta.config("ssid","password")
wifi.sta.connect()

-- Code for waiting for connection

-- Create server
srv = net.createServer(net.TCP) 
srv:listen(80,function(conn)    
conn:on("receive",function(conn,payload) 
    for line in string.gmatch(payload,'[^\r\n]+') do
        s = string.find(line, "GET /&")
        -- If query is there, control robot
        if s ~= nil then
            -- Do stuff with query
            break;
        -- If no query, serve webpage
        else
            file.open("index.html", "r")
            while true do
                s = file.read(1460)
                if s == nil then
                    break
                end
                conn:send(s)
            end
            file.close()
        end
        break
    end
    conn:on("sent", function(conn) conn:close() end)
end)
end)
```

Creating custom hotspot:

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATIONAP)
cfg={}
cfg.ssid="custom_ssid"
cfg.pwd="custom_password"
wifi.ap.config(cfg)
```

So how do I make it so the mobile can access the server? How do I get/set the IP of the server? Basically, I just need it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand but I believe you're really close. Check the documentation for the AP functions at http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/wifi/#wifiap-module.

`wifi.ap.config(cfg)` sets SSID and pwd as you noted. Your client then connects to this AP by joining the network.

If you then print `wifi.ap.getip()` you'll see that the device has the IP address 192.168.1.4 by default. Hence, for clients which joined this network your server is reachable at 192.168.1.4:80 unless you set a custom IP explicitly.

However, the sending of data seems broken. You have multiple `conn:send(s)` (in the loop) yet you also have `conn:on("sent", function(conn) conn:close() end)` which means that the connection will be closed after the *first* `conn:send`! Check the docs at http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/net/#netsocketsend for an example as for how to do that properly.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I got it working. Take an upvote.